# Error in accessing .jnlp file from a web link

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a java application uploaded on a web portal linked to a `.jnlp` file. The link of the file is in a html file `Launch.html` shown as below:

[image]
The error I am getting when I click on launch button is as follows:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>  The page you are requesting cannot
>   be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

launch.jnlp contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>BuisnessInternals</title>
    <vendor>Administrator</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>BuisnessInternals</description>
    <description kind="short">BuisnessInternals</description>
<icon href="Welcome2.png" kind="splash"/>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="BuisnessInternals.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>   
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>   
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eclipselink-2.3.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.persistence-2.0.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/barcode.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="buisnessinternals.mainFrame">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

launch.html contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</h3>
    <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton("launch.jnlp")
    </script>
    <!-- Or use the following link element to launch with the application -->
    <!--
    <a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how can solve it?

Comment: What are the parameters supplied to the script?  Is the app. public, can we visit it, at what URL?  It appears the JNLP does not have the correct path, and that the 404 page returned by the server (probably `text/html` is not recognized as `application/x-java-jnlp-file`).  Check the content type of a document using [this applet](http://pscode.org/mime/form.html).

Comment: The html file has the following code:                                <a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>.                             And the .jnlp file is in the same folder.

Comment: No, copy/paste the complete HTML(/JS) as an edit.  And where is that link where **we** can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the web server needs some extra configuration to correlate the .jnlp file extension with the application/x-java-jnlp-file mime type.

Comment: You mean the web portal where i have uploaded the files?

Comment: Yes. Or use another web server under your control.

Comment: Ok Henry i'll try this this out and defiantly comment on that. This might take me while.

Answer (score 1):

Specify MIME type in your `JnlpDownloadServlet`

```
response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
```

Read this [Java Web Start tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) for clear understanding.

**Edit**

```
<a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>
```

The above html link you specified should work properly, make sure your `launch.jnlp` file path where you kept something like `<a href="/somepath/launch.jnlp">`

Comment: I don't have a JnlpDownloadServlet but instead i have a simple html file with a href to the .jnlp file. in the same folder. Actually i generated it with netbeans which creates the html file and the jnlp file by default.

Comment: can u add your jnlp file content in your question